# Why does this timeout error occur in recursion? (Python)

Tags: python, recursion

I'm tasked with finding all the permutations of a given string (Ex. for string = 'aab' return ['aab','aba','baa']) and I understand recursion is needed to solve this problem. I still have a hard time wrapping my head around recursion, so when I run this, I get a timeout error. Can anyone tell me what exactly is causing it? Been staring at it for a while now. thanks!

```
import numpy as np
per = []

def permutations(string):
    #permute
    if len(string) == 1:
        return string
    global per
    strList = list(string)
    lastElem = len(strList)-1
    for i in range(lastElem+1):
        if i==lastElem:
            return string
        else:
            strList[i], strList[i+1] = strList[i+1], strList[i]
            permutations(str(strList[i+1:]))
            strList[i], strList[i+1] = strList[i+1], strList[i]
    per.append(str(strList))
    ##REMOVE DUPLICATES##
    np.array(per)
    return np.unique(per)
```

Comment: Recursion is never required, it's just often a nice and concise way to formulate code and can perform sufficiently well to choose it. But any recursive solution can be reformulated as a non-recursive one and in many cases that yields a slightly better performing solution (if perhaps less readable).

Comment: Your code is far more complicated than it needs to be, but the primary issue is you're not doing anything with the return value of your recursive call, so it gets lost; but then you're modifying some global variable (which more or less defeats the purpose here).

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a description in your question of how you expect this code to work, so it is easier to point out why it doesn't work like that, because there seem to be a few ideas in the code that have no clear function.

Comment: @Grismar here's the full problem: 

you have to create all permutations of an input string and remove duplicates, if present. This means, you have to shuffle all letters from the input in all possible orders.

Comment: I understood the problem, it's a very standard programming problem (and part of the libraries of python, so I'm assuming you're only doing this as a coding exercise or as part of a course) - what I was suggesting is for you to provide a description of how your *solution* works, so we can see where your code is different from your expectations. If you're just looking for the best implementation, simply use `itertools.permutations`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a string representation of a list in the recursive calls to the function instead of joining each list element. For example, when `strList = ['a', 'a', 'b']`, then `str(strList)` will return `"['a', 'a', 'b']"`. Instead you should use `''.join(strList)` to actually get `"aab"`.

This problem doesn't need to use recursion, in fact you can achieve the result in one line with itertools.permutations.

```
>>> set(''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations('aab'))
{'aab', 'aba', 'baa'}
```

But if you'd like to implement a recursive version, you also need to pass an argument for the current index of the string you have reached. There are plenty of examples online for this exact problem, it just takes a quick google search, and perhaps even on SO.